# Maximum power which can be asked from a PC?

Tags: power, computers

I want to attach an external circuit through a six-pin connector to my computer, which is supplied with 220V.

How can I find the maximum power that the PC can supply to the circuit?

Comment: Do you want to supply the power to your pc through an external circuit? Or do you want to power an external circuit at the same time with the pc?

Comment: I want to power an external circuit at the same time with the pc.

Answer (score 7):

> **How can I find the maximum power**

It's often written on a label on the side of the internal PSU. Since PSUs vary considerably, you'd have to check your specific PSU. You'd have to deduct the power being used by the PC itself whilst your device is attached.

[image]
[image]
Note that the 5V rail of this 400W PSU can supply more power than the 5V rail of the 700W PSU.

> **through a six-pins connector.**

The individual connectors also have limits. The six-pin aux cable can supply 10A at 3.3V plus 5A at 5V - [Ref](http://www.playtool.com/pages/psuconnectors/connectors.html#aux).

Comment: On the lower PSU: notice that 5V × 40A = 200W, which is already higher than the rated 185W. Also 185+216 = 401W. So it is very important to double check if you don't exceed the power rating at given current ratings. Apply 'whichever comes first'-rule.

Comment: You have been really useful. An other related question: if I have a PSU of 400W, what would happen if I ask to the PC, for example, 500W?

Comment: @fortea: I'd expect pulling 500W from a 400W PSu will cause the PSU to shut down (either due to over-current protection or thermal overload protection)

Comment: iCute -- I like it :>